# What do you call a documentation about XML/GraphML's predefined elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, mxgraph, graphml, draw.io

today I have come to read some GraphML (basically just XML) files generated by yEd, and I have found many predefined elements such as UMLClassNode, Geometry, Fill... inside them. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find any documentation regarding those elements on the Internet.

One more scenario is that when I save diagrams from Draw.IO as XML files, I find some particular MXGraph XML elements, but again, I cannot find their format anywhere. How should I look for these kinds of stuff?

Thank you for your time and consideration. I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: It is a schema or DTD, perhaps http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/specification/schema_element.xsd.htm helps.

Answer (score 0):

GraphML, the XML representation format yEd uses for storing diagrams, is specified on [it's official home page](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/). yEd also uses yEd extension schemas, as the first couple text lines of an yEd-created `.graphml` file shows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<graphml
 xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
 xmlns:java="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/1.0/java"
 xmlns:sys="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/primitives/2.0"
 xmlns:x="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yfiles-common/markup/2.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:y="http://www.yworks.com/xml/graphml"
 xmlns:yed="http://www.yworks.com/xml/yed/3"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
    http://www.yworks.com/xml/schema/graphml/1.1/ygraphml.xsd">
<!--Created by yEd 3.18.0.2-->
...
```

Documentation for the extension schemas is available from YWork's website. For example, the namespaces/schemas for "yfiles-common" are linked from https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles/documentation, and the vocabulary for yEd's extensions to GraphML are documented at https://www.yworks.com/xml/schema/graphml/1.1/doc/http___www.yworks.com_xml_graphml/index.html .